# Magento 2 translate error showing curly braces

Tags: magento2.3.0

Just update Magento to 2.3.0 and get these messages.
I tried to remove translation files and do static-content:deploy.
Did not help.

[image]

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025677/magento-2-label-translation-showing-braces/54071075#54071075

Comment: do you have any inline translation? in database check the translation table.

Comment: @magefms did this, didn't help.

Comment: @Korbin yes, i have.

Comment: if you have some inline translation most likely that causes brokken {{{ }}}. Use external translation packs and don't use inline translation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not translation error.

You are getting this error because of you have not installed **Required PHP extensions**
Please check have you installed **php-curl** extension?

You can check required PHP extension list [Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this issue comes when you did not properly disable the configuration or inline translation configuration.

please check the inline translation or any other configuration and make sure you disable the configuration properly which applies to specific mode(developer) and then changed from developer mode to production mode or vice versa.

After that please run the following commands

> ```
> $rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_processed/* generated/code/*
> $php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> $php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> $php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> $php bin/magento cache:clean
> $chmod 777 -R app/ var/ generated/ pub/
> ```