# Child Theme showing strange labels on breadcrumbs, buttons, labels etc.( {{{Home}}{{Home}}{{Home}}{{themeVendor/ThemeName}}})

Tags: addtocart, localisation, breadcrumbs, labels

I have a problem with my child theme in Magento. On the products page it shows labels like "{{{Home}}{{Home}}{{Home}}{{themeVendor/ThemeName}}}" for the breadcrumbs or "{{{Add to Cart}}{{Add to Cart}}{{Add to Cart}}{{themeVendor/ThemeName}}}" on the "Add to Cart" button. Also, every label/phrase in the ordering process looks like this.

I tried to change some of the translations before, so maybe it has something to do with this?

Maybe this was answered before, but since I am completely new to Magento I have no idea what to search for in this case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes may be this issue coming after translation...

Answer (score 0):

Did you install php-curl extension? Look here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/265715/91726 for a similar issue's answer.